# Windows Forms and c# randomizing

Tags: c#, winforms, 2d-games

So I'm making a game in windows forms. I have run into a slight hitch though. When the player is touching the basketball I want the basketball to change to a different lane. So in order to do this, I used the random and .next(1, 4) methods.

For some reason sometimes the basketball will appear on the same road as the player and I have tried everything to make it check for this but nothing works.

Here is the code:

```
private void Hlocal(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // If the player is touching the basketball
            if (Halsey.Location.X == Basketball.Location.X)
            {
                scorenum += 1; // Score
                Score.Text = $"Score: {scorenum}"; // Scoreboard
                Broad = rnd.Next(1, 5); // Picks a random road
                label1.Text = $"{Broad}"; // for debugging
                // After it chooses a road I place it on the road
                switch (Broad)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Basketball.Location = new Point(57, Basketball.Location.Y);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Basketball.Location = new Point(263, Basketball.Location.Y);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        Basketball.Location = new Point(469, Basketball.Location.Y);
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        Basketball.Location = new Point(675, Basketball.Location.Y);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is where it moves the character and changes Hroad var:

```
private void KeyHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyData)
            {
                case Keys.Right:
                    if (Halsey.Location.X == 675)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    Halsey.Location = new Point(Halsey.Location.X + 206, Halsey.Location.Y);
                    Hroad += 1;
                    label2.Text = $"{Hroad}";
                    break;
                case Keys.Left:
                    if (Halsey.Location.X == 57)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    Halsey.Location = new Point(Halsey.Location.X - 206, Halsey.Location.Y);
                    Hroad -= 1;
                    label2.Text = $"{Hroad}";
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Some clarifications:

*Hlocal is an event called everythime the player moves.*

*Halsey is a picturebox which acts as the character sprite.*

*Basketball is a sprite which acts like a coin that adds points.*

*scorenum is the score*

*label1 is just for debugging*

*Broad is the road the basketball is on*

*Hroad is the road the player is on*

*and the basketball locations are the different roads*

Currently, the x points to place sprites on the roads are:
road1 - 57

road2 - 263

road3 - 469

road4 - 675

Comment: There doesnt seem to be a question

Comment: `rnd.Next(1, 4)` will generate values between 1 and 3.

Comment: Yeah sorry for to add it :(

Comment: `do { Broad = rnd.Next(1, 5); } while (Hroad == Broad);`

Comment: Just tried do while and it works better but it still sometimes places on the same road :( @JohnnyMopp

Comment: You could also make a `List<int>` with 1-5. Remove `Hroad` from the list. Then choose a random index in the new list and set `Broad to that value.

Comment: winforms dont have "frames" ... unity and other sorts of games frameworks have frames

Comment: Somehow it still isnt working i have no idea how? What i have now is everytime the player moves it clears the list then adds 1 - 4, removes the players roads, the chooses a random one. @JohnnyMopp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `List<int>` with the roads in it. Then remove the `Hroad` value which leaves a list of available roads. Then select a random one of those:

```
List<int> roads = new List<int>{1,2,3,4};
roads.Remove(Hroad);
int Broad = roads[rand.Next(0, roads.Count)];
```

Comment: Aha I got it working. I changed the Hroad in your answer to Broad(current the road of the ball) and low and behold it works.

Comment: @MatthewAugust Ah. I was assuming `Hroad` and `Broad` were the same at that point. Glad it is working.